# Windows 10: Bitlocker Screen after Hibernation

Tags: windows, windows-10, hibernate, bitlocker

after I've got the following error message at startup, I've tried the link below to fix my problems:

> The Boot Configuration Data files is missing some required information
>
> File: \BCD
>
> Error code: 0xc000000d

http://blogs.catapultsystems.com/chsimmons/archive/2016/08/12/recovering-from-bcd-error-0xc000000d-with-bitlocker-and-hyper-v/

It worked flawlessly but since then, whenever I recover my laptop from hibernation I get the old DOS-like Bitlocker Screen.

I know it's not a real problem, as evrything is working fine, but deep down in me I really dislike the DOS Screen.

So far I tried the following (obviously) without success:

- Deactivating and activating Bitlocker
- Via cmd.exe: bcdedit /set {default} bootmenupolicy Standard
- Via cmd.exe: sfc /scannow

Does anyone of you have a solution for me?
It would be very helpful.

And please excuse my not perfect English, it's not my native language.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For GPT Rebuild BCD
Restart Your System Windows 10 Installation Media.

Select the language - Next
Go To Repair Your Computer

1. Troubleshoot → Advanced options → Command Prompt
2. Choose Command Prompt from the menu

   ```
   Run the command : diskpart

   Run the command : sel disk 0

   Run the command : list vol
   ```

**Verify that the EFI partition is using the FAT32 file system and assign a drive letter to it**

```
Run the command :sel vol <number of volume>

Run the command :assign letter=<drive letter>:

Run the command:exit
```

**In order to repair the boot record :**

```
    Run the command : cd /d <drive letter>:\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\
    Run the command : bootrec /FixBoot
```

**Rebuild the BCD store**

```
 First run the command below to backup the old BCD : ren BCD BCD.old
 Now recreate it using this command: bcdboot c:\Windows /l en-us /s <boot letter>: All
```

Please remember that the `<boot letter>` is replaced with whatever the letter of the drive you are booting from is.

> that is C:\, D:\

Comment: Thats the same as in the link.
But I just did and it didn't fix the problem.
Moreover, it found 0 Windows-Installations...

Comment: Ahh just seen your edit.
I'll try tomorrow when I got my installation media.
I'll keep you up to date.

Comment: No problem. I was not aware of that link. After my research i found you have rebuild the BCD using media.

Comment: I can't get past the second command. Windows is telling me, he can't find the path "C:\boot". What should I do?

Comment: Again Bootrec won't find any OS

Comment: Deactivation Bitlocker didn't do anything good. Is there maybe a problem with Bootrec and EFI/GPT?

Comment: Yes. Is that a problem?

Comment: Please Refer the edited Answer above. Try those step

Comment: You are my hero! It worked like charm! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has warned in the past that you must disable Hibernation mode before utilizing Bitlocker encryption. Bitlocker functions with it, but it's not an ideal practice and Windows boots so quickly now that hibernation is unnecessary, particularly if you're security minded.

Turn off hibernation mode, in power settings, or in group policy. Then follow the steps listed above. If that still fails, I would decrypt, reinitialize the TPM, and encrypt again. If that fails again, I would do a clean install of Windows and give it another shot.

Comment: Do you have any resources on that? I've never read that.

And for the hibernation mode:
I often need to interrupt my work, e.g. while travelling and need to resume where I left.
The problem with sleep mode is, that Bitlocker won't be active, therefore, ma laptop won't be protected